# How to use Python to split on a specific comma

Tags: python

I have a txt file like this:

```
"Adler; David L. (San Jose, CA)", 
"Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)", "Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA) , Reyna; David L. (San Ramon, CA)", 
"Amano; Masaharu (Ibaraki, JP )"
```

this is a file that of people's name and (their city + their state).

and Now I will have to seperate everyrecord one by one.

like this:

```
Adler; David L. (San Jose, CA)

Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)

Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)

Reyna; David L. (San Ramon, CA)

Amano; Masaharu (Ibaraki, JP )
```

and How can I realize this?
I'm not familiar with re so how could we sovle this with re for example?
that is we will divid the word by the  following index like two kinds of comma:

1.

```
"Adler; David L. (San Jose, CA)", 
  "Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)"
```

into:

```
Adler; David L. (San Jose, CA)

Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)
```

2.`Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA) , Reyna; David L. (San Ramon, CA)`

into:

```
Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)

Reyna; David L. (San Ramon, CA)
```

thank you!

Comment: The pattern I can see here is:
"Name (Place)", "Name (Place)", "Name (Place), Name(Place)"
Do you see the difference in placement of quotes in the first two names & last two names?
Is this prevalent in your text file too? Or is it a mistake in your example?

Comment: ?any idea of how to solve it? thanks

Comment: I just edited my example. Please check.

Comment: bingo!that is my want.Name (Place)

Comment: The file is some longer one. No rules to be reproduced. it depends on the original sources and that is by chance of people(place),people(palce) and sometimes it is "people(place)" or sometimes it is "people(place),people(place),people(place)" or maybe"people(place),people(place),people(place),people(place)" or more. No regulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are good for this.

```
txt='"Adler; David L. (San Jose, CA)", "Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)", "Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA) , Reyna; David L. (San Ramon, CA)", "Amano; Masaharu (Ibaraki, JP )"'
import re
for s in re.findall(r'[^\s",(][^",(]*\([^)]*\)', txt):
    print s
```

prints

```
Adler; David L. (San Jose, CA)
Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)
Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)
Reyna; David L. (San Ramon, CA)
Amano; Masaharu (Ibaraki, JP )
```

In the regular expression:

- `[^\s",(]` one character other than whitespace, quote, comma or opening parenthesis
- `[^",(]*` zero or more characters other than quote, comma or opening parenthesis
- `\(` opening parenthesis (must be escaped by \ because it has a special meaning in regex)
- `[^)]*` zero or more characters other than a closing parenthesis
- `\)` closing parenthesis

Comment: thans! that is very helpful and useful!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv) and specify the coma as a separator.

Comment: If the input is well-formed as comma-separated, quoted strings, then CSV should handle it just fine.

Comment: you mean use CSV and set the right sperate commoa to be the one out of the parenthesis mark？

Comment: But  how to handle the commoa in (San Ramon, CA) like this?

Comment: @sikisis: the charater '"' encloses your data, so only comas outside of it will be considered as a separator by the CSV module.

Comment: @sikisis There's a keyword arg [quotechar](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.Dialect.quotechar) that let's you have strings with special characters that aren't broken - it defaults to `"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your file won't contain any security-related stuff, you might just do

```
exec("l = ["+text+"]")
print i for i in l
```

Or, for regex:

```
import re
res = re.findall("([A-Za-z]*?; [A-Za-z]+?( [A-Za-z]\.)?) \(([A-Za-z ]*?, [A-Z]*?)\)", text)
for i in res:
    name = i[0]
    if len(res) == 2: citystate = i[1]
    else: citystate = i[2]
    print name, citystate
```

As long as there are no ending " " before the ")" of the city and state, that should work.

Comment: I am sorry?could you be any more sepecific?

Comment: It is much better to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `eval`; it is safe with untrusted input.

Comment: @sikisis: If you are sure the file does exactly look like you described (only data defined by you, not by the user!), the exec thing should be safe. If somebody would edit the file to look like `]jsfkhajfghkf` it would raise an error, and your program would possibly quit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Strip the quotes off from the text file.
2. Split the string into a list using the ','
3. Learn & use regexes from http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, to extract name & place for each list element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to `python` then I suggest `awk` is perfect for this:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' FPAT="[[:alpha:]]+;[^)]+)" OFS="\n" file
Adler; David L. (San Jose, CA)
Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)
Albert; Richard D. (San Ramon, CA)
Reyna; David L. (San Ramon, CA)
Amano; Masaharu (Ibaraki, JP )
```

`FPAT` is used to set the field pattern, in this case the field pattern is

```
[[:alpha:]]+     # One or more alphabetic character
;                # Followed by a literal semi-colon
[^)]+            # Followed by one or more none ) characters 
)                # Followed by a )
```

`OFS` is used to set the output field separator, here we use the newline character.

Note: this requires `GNU awk`.